# Who will serve ASGI and WSGI when I add daphne to Django?

Tags: python, django, channel, django-channels, asgi

When I add **daphne** in **INSTALLED_APPS** how will it work?

Does it work itself to serve `WSGI` and `ASGI` ?

Or does it work alone to serve `ASGI` only?

And `Gunicorn` still working to serve `WSGI`?

if daphne works alone to serve `ASGI` only, and `Gunicorn` works alone to serve `WSGI` only... that meansI am running two servers in the same time.

right?

i have read the document of Channels and ASGI ... but i did not find any thing talks about this thing .. and how will it act >> or if does it take everything and serve them all.

if thet so, then i have to deploy my project on a server and run daphne only right?

[channels document.](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

[ASGI document.](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daphne is specifically for ASGI applications, and it doesn't replace a `WSGI` server like `Gunicorn` for handling traditional `HTTP` requests.

`Daphne` serves as an `ASGI` server, primarily handling asynchronous tasks like WebSocket connections. It's used for Django Channels.

Daphne does not serve `WSGI` applications. For synchronous `HTTP` requests (WSGI), you still need a traditional `WSGI` server like `Gunicorn`.

If your Django project uses both `ASGI` (for async features) and `WSGI` (for standard HTTP requests), you'll run both Daphne (for ASGI) and a `WSGI` server like Gunicorn simultaneously.

For a project solely using `ASGI` features (like Django Channels), deploy with Daphne. If you have both `WSGI` and `ASGI` components, deploy with both Daphne and a WSGI server.

Some references for you if you need more information.

[Django's Official Documentation on Using Daphne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/daphne/)

[Deploying Django with ASGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/)

[ASGI 3.0 Documentation](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementations.html)

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the official channels docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#http-and-websocket)

> You can **choose** to either use **Daphne for all requests** - HTTP and
> WebSocket - or if you are conservative about stability, keep running
> standard **HTTP requests through a WSGI server and use Daphne only for
> things WSGI cannot do**, like HTTP long-polling and WebSockets. If you
> do split, you’ll need to put something in front of Daphne and your
> WSGI server to work out what requests to send to each (using HTTP path
> or domain) - that’s not covered here, just know you can do it.

So it's your choice, the answer is either.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is the thing that they mentioned here (you’ll need to put something in front of Daphne and your WSGI server to work out what requests to send to each (using HTTP path or domain) - that’s not covered here, just know you can do it) ?

Comment: The thing is a reverse proxy, like Nginx, which I recommend.